# I'm trying to change a CSS element with Javascript but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have tried changing the background color of my website using the javascript. I wanted it to change at certain time. But it doesn't seem working. I have run every set of combinations but the bg color always stays default one described in CSS.

The JS code seems to add new line of code instead of modifying the CSS. How do I know that which part of the code a computer will read first? Is the CSS prioritized first or the inline code/HTML ? TIA

```js
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();

//Keep in code - Written by Computerhope.com
//Place this script in your HTML heading section

document.write('It\'s now: ', hours, '<br><br>');
document.bgColor = "White";

//5am-7am morning
if (hours > 5 && hours < 7) {
  document.write('<body style="background-color: #FFF95D">');
}
//7am-12pm noon
else if (hours > 7 && hours < 12) {
  document.write('<body style="background-color: #B3E5FC">');
}
//12pm-4pm afternoon
else if (hours > 12 && hours < 16) {
  document.write('<body style="background-color: #7E57C2">');
}
//4pm-7pm evening
else if (hours > 16 && hours < 19) {
  document.write('<body style="background-color: #EF5444">');
}
//7pm-10pm Night
else if (hours > 19 && hours < 22) {
  document.write('<body style="background-color: #424242">');
}
//1opm-5am Nighting
else if (hours > 22 && hours < 7) {
  document.write('<body style="background-color: #000000">');
}
```

```css
  body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #455A64;
  font-family: var(--fontFamily);
  font-size: var(--fontSizeMd);
  line-height: var(--lineHeightMd);
```

Comment: When I hard-code the `hours`, color looks to change fine for me. `<body bgcolor="White" style="background-color: #B3E5FC">`

Comment: This code working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) while you use `document.write()`  an HTML document is fully loaded, will delete all existing HTML so use `document.body.style.background` for change color of body.
>
> 2) To change colors automatically use `setInterval`.
>
> 3) change last line from `else if (hours > 22 && hours < 7) {` to `else  {` because there is not number greater than 22 and less than 7.

```
var el = document.getElementById('time');

(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    el.innerHTML = ('It\'s now: ' + hours + '<br><br>');
    //5am-7am morning
    if (hours > 5 && hours <= 7) { document.body.style.background ='#FFF95D'; }
    //7am-12pm noon
    else if (hours > 7 && hours <= 12) { document.body.style.background ='#B3E5FC'; }
    //12pm-4pm afternoon
    else if (hours > 12 && hours <= 16) { document.body.style.background = "#7E57C2"; }
    //4pm-7pm evening
    else if (hours > 16 && hours <= 19) { document.body.style.background = "#EF5444"; }
    //7pm-10pm Night
    else if (hours > 19 && hours <= 22) { document.body.style.background = "#424242"; }
    //1opm-5am Nighting
    else  { document.body.style.background = "#000000"; }
    },1000);
})();
```

```js
var el = document.getElementById('time');

(function(){

  setInterval(function(){
 var now = new Date();
 var hours = now.getHours();
 el.innerHTML = ('It\'s now: ' + hours + '<br><br>');

 //5am-7am morning
 if (hours > 5 && hours <= 7) { document.body.style.background ='#FFF95D'; }
 //7am-12pm noon
 else if (hours > 7 && hours <= 12) { document.body.style.background ='#B3E5FC'; }
 //12pm-4pm afternoon
 else if (hours > 12 && hours <= 16) { document.body.style.background = "#7E57C2"; }
 //4pm-7pm evening
 else if (hours > 16 && hours <= 19) { document.body.style.background = "#EF5444"; }
 //7pm-10pm Night
 else if (hours > 19 && hours <= 22) { document.body.style.background = "#424242"; }
 //1opm-5am Nighting
 else { document.body.style.background = "#000000"; }

 },1000);
  
})();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #455A64;
  font-family: var(--fontFamily);
  font-size: var(--fontSizeMd);
  line-height: var(--lineHeightMd);
}
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```

> You can use of `switch` instead of `else if` like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('time');

(function(){

  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    el.innerHTML = ('It\'s now: ' + hours + '<br><br>');

    switch(true) {
        case (hours > 5 && hours <= 7):
          document.body.style.background ='#FFF95D';
          break;
        case (hours > 7 && hours <= 12):
          document.body.style.background ='#B3E5FC';
          break;
        case (hours > 12 && hours <= 16):
          document.body.style.background = "#7E57C2";
          break;
        case (hours > 16 && hours <= 19):
          document.body.style.background = "#EF5444";
          break;
        case (hours > 19 && hours <= 22):
          document.body.style.background = "#424242";
          break;
        default:
          document.body.style.background = "#000000";
      }

    },1000);

})();
```

Comment: You should really be using a switch statement for this instead of all the if else's

Answer (score 3):

document.write() will basically add new lines code to the document which here is the  html itself.
The objective here is to change just the background-color property of body.
You can use for example :

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of that try this way.

In javascript :
Instead of `document.write()` do this

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="#xxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this instead of document.write:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "some_color";
```

where some_color is one of the colors of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Use the !important attribute when you give the style in the javascript to override the previously specified backgound color.
Example: style='background-color: #fff !important'

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the color of body then use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` or `document.bgColor`

`document.bgColor` gets or sets the background color of the current document.

The `write()` method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a document.

The `write()` method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

```js
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();

//Keep in code - Written by Computerhope.com
//Place this script in your HTML heading section

document.write('It\'s now: ', hours, '<br><br>');
document.bgColor = 'white';

//5am-7am morning
if (hours > 5 && hours < 7) {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF95D';
}
//7am-12pm noon
else if (hours > 7 && hours < 12) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#B3E5FC';  
}
//12pm-4pm afternoon
else if (hours > 12 && hours < 16) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#7E57C2';
}
//4pm-7pm evening
else if (hours > 16 && hours < 19) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#EF5444';
}
//7pm-10pm Night
else if (hours > 19 && hours < 22) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#424242';
}
//1opm-5am Nighting
else if (hours > 22 && hours < 7) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #455A64;
  font-family: var(--fontFamily);
  font-size: var(--fontSizeMd);
  line-height: var(--lineHeightMd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run this code at its boundary time.
e.g at 12 o'clock
it is not satisfying in either condition i.e.(hours<12)and (hours>12) so put "<=" instead of <

Try out this code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var now = new Date();
        var hours = now.getHours();

        //Keep in code - Written by Computerhope.com
        //Place this script in your HTML heading section

        document.write('It\'s now: ', hours, '<br><br>');
        document.bgColor = "White";

        //5am-7am morning
        if (hours > 5 && hours <= 7) {
          document.write('<body style="background-color: #FFF95D">');
        }
        //7am-12pm noon
        else if (hours > 7 && hours <= 12) {
          document.write('<body style="background-color: #B3E5FC">');
        }
        //12pm-4pm afternoon
        else if (hours > 12 && hours <= 16) {
          document.write('<body style="background-color: #7E57C2">');
        }
        //4pm-7pm evening
        else if (hours > 16 && hours <= 19) {
          document.write('<body style="background-color: #EF5444">');
        }
        //7pm-10pm Night
        else if (hours > 19 && hours <= 22) {
          document.write('<body style="background-color: #424242">');
        }
        //1opm-5am Nighting
        else if (hours > 22) {
          document.write('<body style="background-color: #000000">');
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: You should explain why/how this works as a solution, otherwise it provides little value.